# Pop up does not load after log in, but loads if page is then refreshed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, devise

I have a pop up box that invites users to complete a process after they log in. In our regular web app everything works fine. In our mobile web app, the FIRST time the index page is loaded AFTER LOG IN the pop up is not displayed. When the page is RELOADED the pop up does display.

in application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h1").fadeIn(1000);
    $('.fade').delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
    loadPopupBox(); # --------------------------------- line that loads pop up
    $('.popupBoxClose').click( function() {            
        unloadPopupBox();
    });
    function unloadPopupBox() {
        $('.step_pop').fadeOut("slow");
    }    
    function loadPopupBox() {
        $('.step_pop').fadeIn("slow");
    }        
});
```

in index.mobile.erb:

```
<% unless @step1 && @step2 && @step3 && @step4 %>
    <%= render :partial => "steps_pop" %>
<% end %>
```

in _steps_pop.mobile.erb:

```
<div class="step_pop" style="width: 90%; height: 80%; left: 5%; top: 5%; ">
    ... process description then yes or no
</div>
```

We are using Devise for authentication.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you are having the same problem I'm having here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11377137/1476757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of placing the pop up script within:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

I placed it within:

```
$( document ).delegate("#aboutPage", "pageinit", function()
```