# jQuery mobile: toggleClass not working until page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a jQuery Mobile based mobile website, where one of the subpages is showing a complete festival program. The navbar is used for selecting which categories to show in the program, using the jQuery toggleClass function.

Everything works like a charm when the actual URL is accessed directly, or when you refresh the page after it's loaded - but it does not work when you access it from the menu the first time.

Work in progress at this URL:
http://2157.no/mobil/program.html

The page I'm struggling with is the top menu item (Programoversikt). The navbar items for selecting categories won't work until it's refreshed in the browser. After that it'll stay working throughout the session, unless you reload any other pages before accessing it again.

Any ideas? I'm guessing this has something to do with data-prefteching/caching, but I'm a bit out in the blue here...

Could I either force a fresh load of the current page when it's accessed, or prevent it from being prefetched at all?

Comment: Oh joy. Been struggling with this for hours... It was all a matter of adding data-ajax="false" to the link. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Setting data-ajax="false" is a solution but there are also some other ways around. you can read more details here [getting data from MySQL on jquerymobile only when I refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376172/getting-data-from-mysql-on-jquerymobile-only-when-i-refresh-the-page/11377137#11377137)